# Attempting to iterate over characters in a word and insert a new random character, and repeat for each line in a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, global-variables

I'm working on a Python script that will read each line in a file and then iterate over that line, and each subsequent character in the line, to randomly add a new character from a given list of characters.

ex.
My given list of characters is as follows:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
y
x
z
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'repl'
'
'
```

I then want to read out of a file with given words and add in random letters/empty characters (each instance of `repl` gets replaced with an empty string) based on a randomizer. I then want to take the final product of each randomized word and write it to a new line in a separate file.

This is the code I have to get that done currently:

```
import re
import random as rand

lettersDict = {}          
with open('alphabet.txt', 'r') as alpha:
    try:
        for i in range(41):
            letter = alpha.readline()
            if len(letter) == 2:
                re.sub('\'\'', '', letter)
            else:
                pass
            print(letter, i)
            lettersDict[i] = letter
            print(lettersDict)
            
        for k in lettersDict:
            v = lettersDict[k]
            rv = re.sub('\n', '', v)
            print(rv)
            lettersDict[k] = rv
            print(lettersDict[k])
    finally:
        alpha.close()

lineCount = 0
__NextLine__Count = 0
with open('unalteredOpus_Arcanus.txt', 'r') as uoa:
    try:
        for line in uoa:
            lineCount += 1
            print(lineCount)
            print(line)
            lineSplit = re.split(' - ', line)
            print(lineSplit)
            if len(lineSplit) == 2:
                rev = lineSplit.pop(1)
                rev = re.sub(' ', '\'', rev)
                print(lineSplit, rev)
                for c in rev:
                    randomizer = rand.randrange(41)
                    print(randomizer)
                    charInsert = lettersDict[randomizer]
                    if charInsert == '\'repl\'':
                        lettersDict[randomizer] = ''
                        charInsert = lettersDict[randomizer]
                    else:
                        pass
                    print(charInsert)
                    strSplit = re.split(c, rev)
                    print(strSplit)
                    print(len(strSplit))
                    if len(strSplit) >= 2:
                        p1 = strSplit.pop(0)
                        p2 = strSplit.pop(0)
                        rev = "{}{}{}".format(p1, c, p2)
                    else:
                        p1 = strSplit.pop(0)
                        rev = "{}{}".format(p1, c)
                    print(lineSplit, rev)
            elif len(lineSplit) == 1:
                __NextLine__Count += 1
                lineSplit.pop(0)
                lineSplit.append('Page {}'.format(__NextLine__Count))
                print(lineSplit)
            else:
                pass
            try:
                with open("alteredOpus_Arcanus.txt", "w") as aoa:
                    aoa.write("{}{}\n".format(lineSplit, rev))
            finally:
                aoa.close()
    finally:
        uoa.close()
```

Unfortunately, when I run this as is I get a Name Error showing that one of my variables, `rev`, isn't defined. I'm a bit confused as I thought declaring a variable outside of a function made it a named variable, even if it's declared inside a loop. Is that inherently wrong? If so, do I need to explicitly declare the variable as global? I'd like to avoid making any of this a function as of yet because I want to make sure I'm familiar with other concepts before trying to fight with functional programming again. Any advice would be well appreciated.

Comment: You have defined `rev` inside the body of an if-statement. Let's say that during the first iteration of the primary loop the condition of the if-statement is not satisfied, then `rev` will not be defined by the time you do `aoa.write("{}{}\n".format(lineSplit, rev))`

Comment: Oh silly me oh my the first line is escaped. That would explain why it gives a Name Error. So then I can instead write `rev` into the `elif` and `else` statements, though I'm unsure what standard practice is on writing in requirements the make me compensate inside `else` statements.